# Multiple counts on a single column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am currently running a query like the following:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ContactID, a.Code, 
FROM tableA a
JOIN (SELECT ContactID, Code
      FROM tableA
      WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Code, ContactID
      HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1) b
ON (a.Code = b.Code AND a.ContactID = b.ContactID)
WHERE a.ContactID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.Code
```

This returns data that looks like the folloing:

```
table : a    
    +-------+-----------+-----------+
    |   ID  | ContactID |   Code    |     
    +-------+-----------+-----------+
    |   1   |    111    |  abcd2    |   
    |   2   |    111    |  abcd2    |   
    |   3   |    222    |  abcd1    |  
    |   4   |    222    |  abcd1    |   
    |   5   |    222    |  abcd1    |  
    |   6   |    222    |  abcd1    |
    +-------+-----------+-----------+
```

So as you can see I get ContactID's that have more then one of the same Code.

The problem with this is, is that I don't want all this output (real table is much larger). I want a COUNT to go along side the Code column and just show one row for each iteration of Code. Like the following:

```
 +-------+-----------+-----------+------+
 |   ID  | ContactID |   Code    |COUNT |    
 +-------+-----------+-----------+------+
 |   1   |    111    |  abcd2    |   2  | 
 |   3   |    222    |  abcd1    |   4  |
 +-------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Any help on this would be great and I hope I have explained my problem well enough. If not please ask for more information and if this has been answered before please point in that direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `b.JpNayoseAddressCode` coming from? It isn't in the `SELECT` in your sub query.

Comment: Edited so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution and other answers are way to complicated, you don't need the self join when you're simply aggregating with `HAVING Count(x) > 1`:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), ContactID, Code, COUNT(Code) AS [COUNT]
FROM tableA
WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Code, ContactID
HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1
```

Full solution:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c3ca/2)

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
    ([ID] int, [ContactID] int, [Code] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO TableA
    ([ID], [ContactID], [Code])
VALUES
    (1, 111, 'abcd2'),
    (2, 111, 'abcd2'),
    (3, 222, 'abcd1'),
    (4, 222, 'abcd1'),
    (5, 222, 'abcd1'),
    (6, 222, 'abcd1')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT min(id), ContactID, Code, count(Code) as [COUNT]
      FROM tableA
      WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Code, ContactID
      HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c3ca/2/0)**:

```
|   | ContactID |  Code |   |
|---|-----------|-------|---|
| 1 |       111 | abcd2 | 2 |
| 3 |       222 | abcd1 | 4 |
```

Comment: Yeh, his original query with the self-join is too complicated.

Comment: Isn't `COUNT(Code)` the same as `COUNT(*)` which you've already computed?

Comment: @Nick it's not going to change the execution, but yeh, I generally wouldn't `(*)` when doing it for myself.

Comment: @Tanner yeah it just looks nicer when you use the same thing in both parts of the query :)

Answer (score 2):

sub-query

```
select min(ID) as id, ContactID,Code,count(*) as cnt from 

(SELECT a.ID, a.ContactID, a.Code 
FROM tableA a
JOIN (SELECT ContactID, Code
      FROM tableA
      WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Code, ContactID
      HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1) b
ON (a.Code = b.Code AND a.ContactID = b.ContactID)
WHERE a.RetailContactID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.Code
) t group ContactID,Code
```

Comment: @Tanner agreed with you

Answer (score 2):

I would use `exists` instead of subquery :

```
select min(a.id) as id, a.ContactID, a.Code, count(*) as Cnt
from tableA a
where exists (select 1 
              from tableA a1 
              where a1.ContactID = a.ContactID and 
                    a1.Code = a.Code and 
                    a1.id <> a.id
             )
group by a.ContactID, a.Code;
```

Comment: seems a bit over the top when aggregation can solve this problem?!

Comment: @Tanner. . . Ya but i m too late.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your SQL query with one more grouping:

```
SELECT min(a.ID), a.ContactID, a.Code, count(*)
...
GROUP BY a.ContactID, a.Code
ORDER BY a.Code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS 

(
SELECT a.ID, a.ContactID, a.Code, 
FROM tableA a
JOIN (SELECT ContactID, Code
      FROM tableA
      WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Code, ContactID
      HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1) b
ON (a.Code = b.Code AND a.ContactID = b.ContactID)
WHERE a.RetailContactID IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT ID, ContactID, Code, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY ID, ContactID, Code
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: I just wrapped your logic in a cte. Lots of ways to do this, but this should definately work.

Comment: @Tanner lol you are right. Was blindly obsessed with being the first to answer, which I also was not btw.

Answer (score -1):

Use group by in your select query

```
    select x.ContactID, x.Code, [count] = count(x.id) from (
    select id = 1   ,    ContactID  = 111   , Code = 'abcd2'    union all    
    select 2   ,    111   , 'abcd2'    union all    
    select 3   ,    222   , 'abcd1'    union all   
    select 4   ,    222   , 'abcd1'    union all    
    select 5   ,    222   , 'abcd1'    union all   
    select 6   ,    222   , 'abcd1') x  group by x.Code, x.ContactID
```